# Checking type of a field in mongo for all the records

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to convert a field `pincode` in mongo collection `location` from Integer to String. The existing records have these field in Integer format.

```
> db.location.find().limit(1).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56021e0532d9a84a95c6f4ab"),
    "_class" : "com.app.core.entity.Location",
    "pincode" : 626513,
    "district" : "San Jose",
    "city" : "San Jose",
    "state" : "California",
    "countryCode" : "US"
}
```

I ran the following script to do the conversions.

```
db.location.find({pincode: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.pincode = "" + obj.pincode;
    db.location.save(obj);
});
```

However, it was taking too long so I killed the terminal. I am not sure if the field `pincode` has been converted to String in all the records.

I can check for only few of the records, and they have been converted to String successfully.

```
> db.location.find().limit(1).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56021e0532d9a84a95c6f4ab"),
    "_class" : "com.app.core.entity.Location",
    "pincode" : "626513",
    "district" : "San Jose",
    "city" : "San Jose",
    "state" : "California",
    "countryCode" : "US"
}
```

Is there a way I can check if the `pincode` field in all the records have been successfully converted or  not ?

Comment: You could check if there are documents in the collection where the pincode field is a double, i.e. `db.location.find( { pincode: { $type : 1 } } )`. If so, then use the bulk api operations to update the collection using the same filter as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MongoDB's [bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/) to update your collection.

Just run following script by changing `collectionName` to your collection.

```
var bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp(), count = 0
db.bulk.find({pincode: {$exists: true }}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var pincode = doc.pincode.toString; 
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
    "$set": { "pincode": pincode }});
    count++;
    if (count % 100 == 0) {
    bulk.execute();
    bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});
if (count % 100 != 0)    bulk.execute();
```

And you can check it by using following query:

```
db.collection.find({ pincode: { $type: 2 } })
```

You can take `.count` of cursor of above query to get number of `pincode` in string format.